# Magento2 - when customer Sign Out then error occurred: "No such entity with id = 0"

Tags: magento2.2, frontend, customer-account, migration, data-migration

After data migration process I fetched one problem. Problem is when customer Sign Out from the account then this error occurred,

> No such entity with id = 0

When I refresh the page again then customer Sign Out but I see that customer is logged in.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check `customer_group` table in Magento2 database.

Check **NOT LOGGED IN** value in `customer_group_code` field. If it's not available in that field, that means when the customer Sign Out then Magento2 can't get the customer group for `NOT LOGGED IN` group.

Add `NOT LOGGED IN` group in the database, Execute this in SQL,

```
INSERT INTO `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`, `customer_group_code`, `tax_class_id`) VALUES ('0', 'NOT LOGGED IN', '3');
```

And if 'NOT LOGGED IN' value available in that field then set its`customer_group_id` '0'.

```
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
```

This work for me properly.